# NSDate full date for iOS 4.3

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

what is the easy way to show a full date + time using `NSDate`, and also support iOS 4.3?
e.g., `Saturday 30 September, 14:00`.

Comment: I meant using NSDate. Show date like this format: "Saturday 30 September 12:00" and ensure it is supported on iOS 4.3 and higher.

Comment: For different date and time format you can refer [this guide](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-15.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSDate* date= [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter* formatter= [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:  @"eeee dd MMMM , hh:mm"];
NSString* formattedDate= [formatter stringFromDate: date];
```

**EDIT**

Another way:

```
formatter.dateStyle= NSDateFormatterFullStyle;
formatter.timeStyle= NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
```

As stated in the comments that should be the preferred way.

Comment: doesn't work, I get a strange outcome instead of month. I am not sure if I was clear I want this approach to support iOS 4.3 and higher versions too up to 6 say...

Comment: It was "MMMM", I edited it.

Comment: Yes, with MMMM it works! thanks. and will it support all iOS es from 4.3 and upward?

Comment: iOS 4.3 uses tr35-15, while iOS 5+ uses tr35-17. But those two have identical datetime formats, so this should work fine from 4.3 up to the current version (6.0.2).

Comment: Thanks. and a minor comment, how to enable that instead of 7:00 it shows say 19:00!? thanks

Comment: And always use `setLocale:`.

Comment: @user1903992 This case the format would be @"eeee dd MMMM , HH:mm".

Comment: -1 Don't set the date format string like this. Set the `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` properties instead.

Comment: hi dave i wanted to do that using those properties, but still I think the day was not being displayed that way. Anyway I will check how to do it using properties too, and let you know if smth interesting comes out. ps. Ramy Al Zuhouri thanks -- I found the HH:mm format too, was again wondering whether it was Ok for iOS 4.3, but I guess it is. thanks.

Comment: What to say? It's a matter of preferences, I added also this way for who likes it.

Comment: @user1903992 watch session 244 from WWDC 2012 for what you should do when the styles don't suffice.

Comment: The problem with manually formatting date-time is that people in different regions use different date-time formats. Even within English-speaking areas there are at least three mainstream date formats and more less-popular ones, let alone other languages. It really is important as a programmer (or UI designer, really) to respect these.

Comment: Alright you convinced me,edited to write that the below method should be the preferred one.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Why do you say to always use `setLocale:`? The formatter defaults to the current locale. You only need to call `setLocale:` is you need some other specific locale.

Comment: I dont have much ideas, but if you dont use dateStyle/timeStyle its good to use setLocale: -This was someone's comment in some answer... So from there I follow this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want localized date/time:

```
NSString *s = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date dateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
```

In practice this is usually too much though. Your example can be obtained by using `NSDateFormatterLongStyle` for date and `NSDateFormatterShortStyle` for time.

[The Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).